# WCF Service as a separate library - DI with Ninject

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control

This is my project diagram (in shortcut). I'm using Ninject to resolve DI in my solution.

- MyWCFService

  - App_Start

    - NinjectWebCommon.cs
  - web.config
- Friends.Implementation

  - Friends.svc

    - Friends.svc.cs
- Friends.Contract

  - IFriends.cs
- DAL.Implementation

  - Blebleble.cs
- DAL.Contract

  - IBlebleble.cs

I have a problem with my WCF Service in `Friends.Implementation` library.

When I have Friends.svc and Friends.svc.cs file in `MyWCFService`, everything is OK (DI and Ninject works).

But when I move Friends service into separate library, I get this error:

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it
>   does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the
>   problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of
>   the type to the host.

Why I get that error? How to resolve it?

This is my service code:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XYZ.Services.Friends" CodeBehind="Friends.svc.cs" Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

.CS file

```
    public IAccountService accountService { get; set; }
    public IFriendsService friendsService { get; set; }

    public Friends(IAccountService _acc, IFriendsService _friends)
    {
        this.accountService = _acc;
        this.friendsService = _friends;
    }
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For service in a separate library you should remove `CodeBehind="Friends.svc.cs"` property from `ServiceHost` and `Service` property should match with the fully qualified assembly name of you service implementation Type

Comment: it is not a solution. For the same service, without IoC and constructor everything works fine.